# php can not execute after selected mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

here is my code, as you can see, I just wanna to connect mysql then insert a info field, but it seems not execute the next code after **selected the db code**, I am a newer in php, and it did not return an error, so I do not know where am I wrong..

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo "show" ?><br>
Your email address is: 


<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "123456";

// 创建连接
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// 检测连接
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "mysql successed connected.";


mysql_select_db("flowers", $conn) or die("database flowers failed".mysql_error()) ;

echo "database successed";

$sql="INSERT INTO flowers (username, password)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$conn))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

echo "1 record added";


mysql_close($conn);

?>
</body>
</html>
```

[test demo info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8B98.png)
and here is the db info:
[dn info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fr6T5.png)

I use ubuntu 16.04 apache2

Comment: `mysql_*` doesnt work with `mysqli`. Your database selection and query will currently fail. You also will be open to sql injections if you dont parameterize that query. An email as a password also isn't secure.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements as described in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: Thanks, I will learn more about the **SQL injection**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the main issue here is that you are using a combination of mysql_ and mysql functions.  Note that mysql has been depreciated since PHP5 and has been completely removed in PHP7 so you should be using the newer mysqli or PDO.  I personally use PDO, however have kept your code with mysqli.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "56lj0721";

// 创建连接
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// 检测连接
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "mysql successed connected.";


mysqli_select_db($conn,"flowers") or die("database flowers failed".mysqli_error()) ;

echo "database successed";

$sql="INSERT INTO flowers (username, password)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]')";

if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

echo "1 record added";


mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

You should also really be using prepared statements to help prevent SQL Injection.  You can read more here for [mysqli.](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

It's also important to remember that you should be validating your $_POST['name'] and $_POST['email'] values as well, which I have not included.

If you want to read further about PDO, take a look [here.](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)

Comment: change `mysqli_select_db("flowers", $conn)` ==> `mysqli_select_db($conn,"flowers");`

Comment: I've updated it, thanks.

Comment: The problem has finished.Very thanks your help, by the way, the second **if** also seems should be changed like mysqli_*($conn, args) not mysqli_*(args, $conn)

Comment: My apologies, I clearly didn't proof this as well as I thought I did.  I'll edit the original answer just incase anyone else looks at this.  Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You have these two statements in your php code.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
        ...
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
```

You should get rid of the second one if you must use the `mysql_` interface to run your query.

You should also know, with respect, that **only a fool uses the `mysql_` interface in 2017.** It has been deprecated for years, for reasons of cybersecurity, and is going away soon.

Comment: lose this statement **only a fool uses the mysql_ interface in 2017**

Comment: And by the way its not going away soon, its gone already